# Having an HTTP error 500 after migrating a website

Tags: apache2, php

Guys I'm having an `HTTP error 500` after trying to migrate another site to an `Ubuntu 16.04LTs virtual server`. My other websites are working in these server but this one gives and error when I'm trying to access in my browser.

I looked inside my `error.log` and found this:

**EDIT:** I removed the contents of my `error.log` and triggered the error once again. Here's the output:

```
[Wed Dec 06 11:45:40.769721 2017] [:error] [pid 23568] [client 121.97.63.220:63265] PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/brainsmartsuccess.com/public_html/wp-includes/load.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/brainsmartsuccess.com/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 19
[Wed Dec 06 11:45:40.769847 2017] [:error] [pid 23568] [client 121.97.63.220:63265] PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/html/brainsmartsuccess.com/public_html/wp-includes/load.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/brainsmartsuccess.com/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 19
[Wed Dec 06 11:45:40.769862 2017] [:error] [pid 23568] [client 121.97.63.220:63265] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/brainsmartsuccess.com/public_html/wp-includes/load.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/brainsmartsuccess.com/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 19
```

I've set the permissions for the specific files as stated in the logs but having no success on removing the HTTP error 500. What permission does it need and what specific file do I need to set the permission?

A sample command would be very helpful -I'm a bit newbie here, thanks!

Comment: Tell me if i need to update my question and I'll add details. Thanks!

Comment: I assume you've noticed those Permission Denied errors?  You need to make sure that `www-data` has `+rx` permissions on all directories in the path tree from the root of the drive up to where all the files and such are stored.  Fix that, and you will be able to fix the HTTP 500 error.

Comment: @ThomasWard I already did that, but still no progress. Any ideas?

Comment: have you checked apparmor logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be more precise: the process user who runs the webservice has to have read and executable rights `+rx` on all files and directories from the directory root `/` through to `/var/www/html/brainsmartsuccess.com/public_html/wp-settings.php`.

With Apache Webserver the child processes are run with a non-login user, normally `www`, `apache`, `nobody` or such.

In the `httpd.conf` look for the `User` directive.

Therefore if the directories and files belong to another user, you would need to put the `apache` user in the same group (hint: `ls -l` ) or make the files/dirs 'other' read- and executable (`chmod o+rx file/dir`).

If unix file permissions are correct: do you have selinux activated? (sestatus)
Unlikely but feasible: do you have file acls activated? (You would see a mount option 'acl' in the mount.